# Error : Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'Or' accepts this number of arguments

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq, predicate

I am using LINQ statement that will return me result that satisfies the condition. Here is my statement for that.

```
predicate = predicate.And(Function(n As DataRow) n("VALUE") < 10)
```

When I build my project it will display compile time error with Message

**"Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'Or' accepts this number of arguments."**

**EDIT** Here is my error screenshot and predicate type for further reference.
[image]

after building - rebuilding multiple time somehow it manages to compile and my application will start up. It is very annoying for me as to start up my application i need to build it multiple times.

I have search through internet but did not found any useful forums. Can some one suggest me what is an actual problem. Is there any .Net Framework, CLR issue?

Thanks in advance. Any suggestions would be highly appreciable.

Comment: what type is predicate?

Comment: Are you sure that's the statement that's giving the error?

Comment: @AlexB. my predicate is type of                                              Dim predicate As System.Linq.Expressions.Expression(Of Func(Of DataRow, Boolean)) = PredicateBuilder.True(Of DataRow)()

Comment: @ChrisDunaway yes This statement is giving me compile time erros..

Comment: I have update my question and add error screenshot for the reference.

Comment: I cannot see what is wrong.  That line of code looks ok to me.  I typed that line into a test VB project and I don't get the error.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway Even I too tried this. It will works .. but it is not working here.. Any IDEA..?